# How to select rows in cassandra for indexing in solr

Tags: solr, cassandra

I have rows in cassasndra, how would I go on about quering those rows in order to index them for example in solr. What query or what way should i use in order to query all those rows in cassandra once?

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using? What you mean by "query once"? If rows changes their content you don't want update your data in solr?

Comment: I mean once one time then I would repeat the whole process updating data in solr, so at least once

Answer (score 4):

Please find below the example to integrate Cassandra and Solr:

```
CREATE TABLE tutor (
id int,
name text,
org text,
dep text,
sal text,
place text,
PRIMARY KEY ((org),name)

)

cqlsh:test> select * FROM tutor;

org | name | dep | id | place | sal    
------+------+------+----+---------+------    
org1 | abc | dep1 | 1 | sanjose | 4500    
org1 | bbb | dep1 | 2 | sanjose | 5500    
org2 | ccc | dep1 | 3 | sanjose | 5500    
org2 | ddd | dep2 | 4 | sanjose | 5500    
org2 | eee | dep3 | 5 | sanjose | 4500    
org2 | fff | dep4 | 6 | sanjose | 7500
```

Requirements for SOLR and Cassandra integration:

SOLR version:

solr 4.9.0

Lib/Jar:

Cassandra :

cassandra-all-1.2.5.jar

libthrift-0.6.0.jar

cassandra-thrift-1.2.5.jar

Daata Import Handler:

solr-dataimporthandler-4.9.0.jar

solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.9.0.jar

MySql:

mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar
In Solor: Following files to be update:

• dataconfig.xml
• schema.xml
• solorconfig.xml
• dataconfig.xml

Here we have to update the JDBC connector for CASSANDRA.

```
< dataConfig>    
< dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"    
driver="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver"    
url="jdbc:cassandra://10.234.31.231:9160/test"    
autoCommit="true"/>    
< document name="content">    
< entity name="test"    
query="SELECT id,org,name,dep,place,sal from tutor" autoCommit="true">    
< field column="id" name="id" />    
< field column="org" name="org" />    
< field column="name" name="name" />    
< field column="dep" name="dep" />    
< field column="place" name="place" />    
< field column="sal" name="sal" />    
< entity>    
< document>    
< dataConfig>
```

schema.xml

```
< field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />    
< field name="org" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />    
< field name="dep" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />    
< field name="place" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />    
< field name="sal" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

Solorconfig.xml

```
< ! - - Add your library Path - →    
< lib dir="/home/solr/lib" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*.jar" />    
< lib dir="/home/solr/lib" regex="cassandra-jdbc-.*.jar" />    
< lib dir="/home/solr/lib" regex="cassandra-all-.*.jar" />    
< lib dir="/home/solr/lib" regex="cassandra-thrift-.*.jar" />    
< lib dir="/home/solr/lib" regex="libthrift-.*.jar" />    
. . . . . . . . . . .    
. . . . . . . . . . . . .    
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

< requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
< lst name="defaults">    
< str name="config">dataconfigCassandra.xml    
< /lst>
```

Comment: does this automatically pick up on changes to the cassandra data?

Comment: Why is a mysql connector jar included?  Is a mysql instance necessary?

Comment: Where do I have to copy these files?

Comment: Add all the Jar Files under Lib/Jar

Comment: I wonder how would we do this in the latest version? And what path these files go?
dataconfig.xml, schema.xml, solorconfig.xml

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how is your setup (which language you are using), but probably the best is to use a Cassandra client library and write an applications to query all the entries (rows) of your cassandra "column family" (tables) and then write the data you want to index from each row in Solr. Here you have a nice overview of several clients for cassandra: http://www.datastax.com/download/clientdrivers.

To perform the "read all entries" you can perform the following "native query":

```
select * from columnfamilyname;
```

This will depend very much on the client library you use... but I imagine most of the clients allow you to do such "native queries" (like the ones you perform in Cassandra cassandra-cli or cqlsh).

Be careful how big is your DB to perform this query... In that case if you if they are indexed/ordered (by key) you can perform a query such as: `select * from columnfamily where indexkey > 101 limit 100 allow filtering`.

After you create the "initial index" in Solr, most probably you should also use an update method that keeps solr index updated with new entries of the Cassandra DB.

Comment: that's my problem, what if I have a big DB `select * from column`  it wouldn't fit in my memory and I can't have like in mysql a query with a for example `limit 500,10` that doesn't exist in cassandra

Comment: yes you can do that in cassandra `limit 500`... no problem! - e.g.: `select * from columnname limit 500`... However, you need to develop something different, based on the keys so that you can read them in intervals, for example if you store them by "date"/"time" you could read the first 500, then next queries from the last time seen with limit of 500... etc. Can you do that in your tables?

Comment: can't you do that only with columns, not rows? I mean index them and and save them sorted by time and then do that thing with `limit`. Problem is you can save only 2 billion columns in a row. Can you do it with rows too? Like in the single id key table section [http://rollerweblogger.org/roller/entry/composite_keys_in_cassandra](http://rollerweblogger.org/roller/entry/composite_keys_in_cassandra). Can you do a `select * from bite where score> 101 limit 100` even though score is indexed? I tried it you can't. Am I not understanding what you say, am I doing maybe something wrong?

Comment: I made an update on my answer... when I was referring to "column" I meant "column family" (or "table"), sorry... and the idea is indeed to index the rows with a single or composite key. Then you can query it (but if they are not "ordered" indeed you will may have problems). If they are indexed/ordered (by score, in your example) you can perform a query such as the one your refer, only you need to "allow filtering": `select * from bite where score > 101 limit 100 allow filtering` that should work.